# django 2.0 how to show the filtered list of products

Tags: django

I am new to python and django. I am trying to create a shopping site. I have a few categories and each category has subcategories. From the home page, when i click on a category, i want to see the subcategory related only to that category. Currently i am seeing a list of all subcategories (not just one category's subcategory but all the subcategories). Please guide me how to achieve this.

My models.py is as follows:

```
from django.db.models import CASCADE

class Category(models.Model):
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

     class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return '/category/{slug}/'.format(slug=self.slug)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Subcategory(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='subcategory', on_delete=CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ('name',)
         verbose_name = 'subcategory'
         verbose_name_plural = 'subcategories'

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

My admin.py is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Subcategory

admin.site.register(Category)


class SubcategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}
    class Meta:
        model = Subcategory

admin.site.register(Subcategory, SubcategoryAdmin)
```

My views.py is as follows:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Category, Subcategory

class CategoryListView(ListView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = 'category/home.html'

class SubcategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Subcategory
    queryset = Subcategory.objects.filter(name='Jeans')
    print(queryset)
    template_name = 'category/detail.html'
```

In the above code i am trying to filter with a subcategory name called Jeans. But what i want is when i click on a category say Men, my url will display localhost:8000/category/Men
So i want to display all the subcategory under Men category. I don't know how to achieve this.

My urls.py (main) is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from category.views import CategoryListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', CategoryListView.as_view()),
    path('category/', CategoryListView.as_view()),
    path('category/', include('category.urls')),
]
```

The category/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import SubcategoryListView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', SubcategoryListView.as_view()),
]
```

My home.html is as follows:

```
{% for object in object_list %}

<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.name }}</a></br>

{% endfor %}
```

My detail.html is as follows:

```
{% for object in object_list %}

<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.slug }}</a></br>

{% endfor %}
```

Highly appreciate all the help and guidance.

Comment: Typically a `detail.html` shows the *details* of a specific element, whereas a `model_list.hml` shows the list of items.

Comment: This code wouldn't show all subcategories though, it would show the single category named "Jeans". (And I don't understand why you've posted the admin class, that seems irrelevant since this question is not about the admin.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman, this is the first time i am working on django, so was not aware what all info will be needed to analyze my question. Hence posted the admin.py as well. 
As i had mentioned, i tried to filter on Jeans and it works that way, but what i want is not achieved by that Jeans filter. Hence requesting for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than defining a `queryset` attribute in your SubcategoryListView class, you need to override the `get_queryset` method. This should use the slug to filter by the parent category.

```
class SubcategoryListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'category/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Subcategory.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug])
```